# Passing a Collection from VBA to a form

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a an MS Access database with nine tables.  The main form will be driven by a query linking the two main tables.  When I pull up any one record ("family within a house"), I have a lot of variable data to pull into the form (how many family members, names of each, other specific information) to retrieve from the other seven tables.  I created a VBA module, linked to this form, which is triggered when a record is loaded.  The code aggregates all the family member data into a Collection of "person" elements.  All of that works, as evidenced by the "Immediate" window in VBA.  The "person" object is defined as a Class Module with all the relevant attributes (firstname, lastname, email, is-parent/is-child, etc).

Where I'm stuck:  how do I access the collection within the form, so I can start populating elements?  I haven't been able to find any documentation to do this, nor any similar questions asked/answered online.  Next step will be creating all the elements dynamically, but right now, being able to create a static element and setting the control source to (at least some component/value within) the collection would be a huge help.

My VBA form module has a method, "Private Sub Form_Current()", which generates the collection when the current record is changed.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: No Q/A on that as that is not needed on access. You ignore one of best features of it if you do it like that, On Ms Access you bind the form to a query and then you bind the forms controls to the fields of the query (in form design mode). No code needed! Search for some tutorials.

Comment: I need each record within the form to contain all information about all family members.  Doing one big query means each family member shows up as a separate record, and that doesn't even consider the ancillary attribute tables.

Comment: Just a matter of query design, Show sample data and expected output as text formated as [table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)!

Comment: It's a database to track neighborhood membership.
Tables:
- house: to track physical residence (primary info)
- house-family: n-to-n linkage to family (to track move-ins/outs)
- family: to group all members of household
- person: each distinct family member
- person-volunteer: n-to-n for persons to volunteer roles
- volunteer: each category of volunteer opportunities
Each record in the form would have all this information for a given house, each family member, and each volunteer sign-up for a given year.  "advance one record" should move house, not merely "person".

Comment: We need sample data and expected result. Add additional infos to question (edit) don't hide in comments. Take the [tour] and read [ask]! After you added the infos and we buld the query, I show you how to use the collection. But for that you should have shown the relevant code (Form_Current and the class(es)). Btw not all people in a household must belong to family.

Answer (score -1):

Got my answer:  "you don't".  Set the element values in code, rather than trying to pass the collection the form.